# Powershell cmdlet to get all distribution lists where name contains "BI" and "Symphony"

Tags: azure-powershell

I am searching for all distribution lists that contain the name "BI" and "Symphony".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*BI*" -or $_.Name -like "*Symphony*"}
```

or:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter 'name -Like "*BI*" -or name -Like "*Symphony*"'
```

If you want to get the distribution lists which contain **BOTH** "BI" and "Symphony", use:

```
Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*BI*" -and $_.Name -like "*Symphony*"}
```

or:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter 'name -Like "*BI*" -and name -Like "*Symphony*"'
```

BTW, if you want case sensitive (eg. you only want to get the distribution list whose name contains "BI" rather than "bi"), use `-clike`:

```
Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -clike "*BI*" -or $_.Name -clike "*Symphony*"}
```